# better performance for aspx page

Tags: asp.net, performance, webforms

When i watch my website in firebug (net tab),aspx pages are too long to loaded.How can reduce this load time?[image: firebug show]. this page is a text and image only and has a little DB query.

this my code:

      Public Function SelectForShow() As DataTable

       Try

           Dim query As String = "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Tbl_News WHERE NewsConfirm ='True' ORDER BY NewsID DESC "

                           Using sqlcon As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)

 
                   Dim sqlAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlcon)

                    Dim Dt As New DataTable()

                    sqlAdapter.Fill(Dt)

                    Return Dt

            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw ex
            End Try
        End Function

and get data in repeater

Comment: That depends what your code is doing when the page is requested.

Comment: Wow this is a very broad subject that isn't intended for SO. If you do some research online you'll find a lot of articles on the subject. Speed optimization can occur on many levels, first step would be to identify the actual bottlenecks.

Comment: this a text and image only and three is no receiving data from server in this page

Comment: Please guide me more @Bartdude.write some of these bottlenecks

Comment: What code is running on your ASP page... That is where your slowness is. do you run any DB queries? Read content from the file system? Etc.

Comment: @scunliffe yes.I run a very simple DB query.Buy what is the meaning of "Read content from the file system"

Comment: If you comment out the code that runs the query and re run the page is it much faster?  If so can you post the SQL query... It may reveal something that isn't obvious.

Comment: @scunliffe Performance is better without query.  this my code:

Comment: Is your NewsConfirm DB column data type actually a string? Or is it a bool, int(1), or bit? Also does your NewsId column have an index (or is it the primary key?)

Comment: @scunliffe NewsConfirm=boolean and NewsId has an index.Does low performance depend on using ajax? Because i used ajax in my site.Thanks alot for your guidance.